# Selenium ActionChains working on some PCs, not others

Tags: python, selenium

I'm developing a data scraping script using Selenium and Python and I've got the following line of code which works on my Ubuntu PC, my wife's Windows PC but not my colleague's Windows PC.

```
ActionChains(driver).context_click(inputElement).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).click().perform()
```

We're in the UK and he is in Canada is the only difference I know of.

**EDIT**

What I've realised is happening, but I do not know how to resolve, is the Keys.ARROW_DOWN is being performed on the webpage and not on the context_click element.  Any thoughts?  Is this a Chrome issue?

Comment: What are the symptoms? Any errors on your colleague's PC?

Comment: He's sent me a video of it but not the traceback which I've requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I rewrote using Firefox instead of Chrome and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a timing issue related to the quality of the network connection to the target site.

I'd strengthen it by introducing an Explicit Wait for the [`inputElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits), use the `WebDriverWait` with `element_to_be_clickable` Expected Condition before starting the action chain.

You may also add a "scroll into view" of the element to tackle potential browser/resolution/etc specific layout issues:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", inputElement)
```

Comment: I've build in an explicit pause and sent it to him to test but I don't think this is the problem.  He's video'd it for me and I can see the context_click (ie right click) taking place but not the going down and clicking open in new tab which is what it is meant to do.